# having gradle.projectsEvaluated in custom plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How can I move the following code snippet to my custom gradle plugin?

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    assemble.dependsOn(myCustomPluginTask)
}
```

I tried the following in the custom gradle plugin, but got "No such property: assemble for class: CustomGradlePlugin".

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.apply(plugin: 'java')

    project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        assemble.dependsOn(myCustomPluginTask)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What exactly you're asking? In custom plugin you will be given an instance of `Project` class via `apply` method. Here's where it can be done.

Comment: I want to run the myCustomPluginTask before the assemble task. I have no idea how to put that logic into the custom gradle plugin. Right now, I use the above snippet in the project build.gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you **need** to do it within `projectsEvaluated`?

The [Gradle Life Cycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) can be a bit confusing when starting out. I recommend you read and understand it thoroughly before attempting your own plugin.

You can probably ignore the `projectsEvaluated` part (because you're in a plugin and not your `build.gradle`) and just do this:

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.apply(plugin: 'java')

    project.task('myCustomPluginTask') {
        print "This is called in the Configuration Phase"
        doLast {
            print "This is called during the Execution phase"
        }
    }

    project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn project.tasks.myCustomPluginTask

}
```